# Specified element is already a logical child of another element

Tags: wpf, invalidoperationexception

I hope this doesn't get marked as duplicate since my problem is kinda complex, so none of the other answers helped. I have a class called 'ControlChoiceModule' that generates a System.Windows.Controls object based on the type of property it deals with (String - TextBox, Boolean - CheckBox, DateTime - DatePicker, etc..). 
It has two dictionaries:

```
public static class ControlChoiceModule
{

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> TypeToControl = new Dictionary<Type, object>
    {
        {typeof(bool), new CheckBox() },
        {typeof(DateTime), new DatePicker() }

    };
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, DependencyProperty> ControlToProperty = new Dictionary<Type, DependencyProperty>
    {
        {typeof(TextBox), TextBox.TextProperty },
        {typeof(CheckBox), CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty },
        {typeof(DatePicker), DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty }

    };
```

The purpose of the other one is just for binding. And here are the two methods:

```
   public static object GenerateControl(Type theType, Binding B)
    {
        object O;
        if (TypeToControl.ContainsKey(theType))
        {
            O = TypeToControl[theType];
        }
        else
        {
            O = new TextBox();
        }

        SetBinding(O, B);
        return O;

    }

    private static void SetBinding(object O, Binding B)
    {
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(O as DependencyObject, ControlToProperty[O.GetType()], B);
    }
```

Now the purpose of all this is to generate an insertion window for a certain class, generically. So the windows loops through all of the class's properties and, based on the type, generates an appropriate field for it.

```
   private void GenerateInsertionOrUpdatePage(string windowText)
    {
        var w2 = new InsertionWindow();
        w2.DataContext = this.DataContext;
        w2.Title = windowText;
        w2.Show();

            foreach (var P in ReturnPropertyList())
            {
                if (P.Name != "SearchableString" && P.Name != "Id" )
                {
                    Label L = new Label();
                    L.Content = P.Name + ":";
                    w2.InsertionStackPanel.Children.Add(L);

                    Binding B = new Binding();
                    B.Path = new PropertyPath("NewT." + P.Name);
                    B.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                    B.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

                    **w2.InsertionStackPanel.Children.Add(ControlChoiceModule.GenerateControl(P.PropertyType, B) as UIElement);**

            }
            }
    }
```

The method above gets called on a click of a button. The first time I click it, it works just fine. But when I click it again, I get the error from the title (on the line marked with **).
Any idea why this happens?
Thanks

Comment: The GenerateControl method always returns the same control instance when the type is contained in the TypeToControl dictionary. As soon as you try to add the same instance to the StackPanel another time, you'll get the exception.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer.
I managed to solve it by changing the first Dictionary to <Type, Type>, and then using O = Activator.CreateInstance(TypeToControl[theType]);